# Are these latest anticipated images of JWST released to public?

Tags: nasa, james-webb-telescope

I came across this line from [here](https://www.digitalcameraworld.com/news/james-webb-space-telescope-images-are-so-beautiful-they-bring-scientists-to-tears):

> These **latest anticipated images** (around 10-20 predicted) however are said to be so beautiful
> that Associate Administrator for NASA’s Science Mission Directorate, Thomas Zurbuchen, was very
> nearly brought to tears when he first viewed them, as stated in a recent press conference.

Comment: What exactly is your question?  The link states they will be released to the public on 12 July.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are these latest anticipated images of JWST released to public?

Not yet. The article to which you linked started with

> The James Webb Space Telescope is set to drop its first gallery of deep-space astronomy shots on July 12 and we can't wait

They'll have to wait, and so will you. The release is a week away.

Comment: TBH, I too can't wait. But I'll have to.